# Data model in neo4j

Tags: java, database, neo4j

I am using neo4j in my application where i have data model something like:

There are many type of resources like car,truck,room,computer,chair etc,these resources have some properties in common but other properties are different for each type of resource.

So i can model resources in two ways :

1. All should be considered as Resource(Node-Label) and will have a property 'type' which can have value like car,truck etc.
2. Each type should be considered as node label and will have its own properties only.

Which one is better?

Comment: which ever one that is easier to draw on a whiteboard.

Comment: Use :Resource:Track, :Resource:Car etc. :Resource for the common attributes and the other labels for the other types.

Answer (score 3):

You can also assign multiple labels on e.g. a Car:

```
CREATE (mercedes:Car:Resource {color:'red', ...})
```

This way you'll find the node when looking for generic resources as well as when looking specifically for cars.

Using a `type` property is a anti-pattern in most cases due to the invention of labels in Neo4j 2.0.